# C# How to add custom fields to an activity in getstream.io?

Tags: c#, getstream-io

I want to add Custom Fields in getstream.io activity. How to do that? I was trying to add by using dictionary, the activity gets added but the extra fields are not visible in getstream.io application. If extra fields got added then how can I view them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# API client allows you to add custom fields with the `SetData` Activity method

```
public void SetData<T>(string name, T data);
```

and to read them back with the `GetData` method

```
public T GetData<T>(string name);
```

Eg.

```
Task.Run(async () => {
    var APIclient = new StreamClient("key", "secret");
    var feed = APIclient.Feed("user", "sajad");

    var activity = new Activity("sajad", "say", "hello world!");
    activity.SetData("api-client", "c-sharp");

    await feed.AddActivity(activity);

    var response = await feed.GetActivities(0, 10);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", response.Results[0].GetData<String>("text"));

}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```